# Select drop down and autocomplete uniqness

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I have a div that contains a drop down and an auto complete input.
I also have a link to add another field with the same drop down and auto complete combination.

The problem I am trying to solve is that you cannot have the same drop down and autocomplete combination.

How can I check for this uniqueness?

Im not sure how to begin tackling this problem.
I created a small [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dvfcfu8h/3/) for visual examples. The example does not work, is just for visuals only.

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <select>
    <option>Select an option</option>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
  </select>
  <input class="tags">
</div>

<a href="#" onClick='clone_div()'>Add another</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C"
  ];
  $( ".tags" ).each(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
});
function clone_div(){
  $('.ui-widget:first-child').clone().prependTo('.ui-widget:first-child');   
}
```

In this example, there should only be 20 possible combinations possible.

If anyone could help, that would be amazing.

**UPDATE**

jsfiddle does not seem to be pulling jQuery correctly at the moment.
This code was never meant to work, it was just a visual example, but I updated the code and here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojrRLw) to it.

Comment: I checked your code and there is error "clone_div is not defined", check the browser devTools by clicking F12

Comment: I made changes to your code, you can check here: https://jsfiddle.net/shhade/dvfcfu8h/4/

Comment: I submitted a codepen. jsfiddle is not loading jquery properly right now so the code will not work.